# How to refresh opener when using emodal

Tags: javascript

I am using bootstrap easy modal extension opening another page using iframe.

```
var options = {
            url: url,
            title:title,
            size: eModal.size.xl
            };
        eModal.iframe(options);
```

Does anyone knows how to refresh the opener page after modal is closed.

I have tried `="window.opener.location.reload();"` it does not work.

Thanks
Kam

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
window.top.location.reload();
```

Comment: Great! accept the answer by clicking the check mark provided that you are not expecting anything more.